# assembly error when installing on a 64 bit windows 7

Tags: installation, 64-bit, python

I tried installing both the 32bit and 64 bit of python on my 64 bit CPU but I'm still getting this error:

[image]
[image]

My OS information:

[image]

Comment: Did you updated your Windows .NET Framework to latest update?

Comment: yes, .4 framework

Answer (score 0):

Python is failing to install Microsoft Visual C++ 9 Redistributable on your machine.

There are two things that you can try:

1. Try to manually install the VC++ redist installed by Python. This may solve your problem, or atleast help you get a better error message.
2. Check if VC++ 9 is already installed on your machine. Many a times, Windows Update upgrades VC++ 9 to a higher version than ones available on Microsoft sites. However many installers do not handle the scenario that the machine may have a higher version of VC++ than they are trying to install and fail. Incase you have VC++ 9 installed, you can either uninstall VC++ 9 and let Python install VC++ 9. Or if you are adventurous, figure out the exact registry key used by python to determine if VC++ is installed and add that registry key to your machine so that it skips installing VC++.

Comment: I already have the latest version, I tried uninstalling but I still got the same error.

Comment: @Hermione did you try unistall VC++ 9? It must have given a more descriptive error

Comment: Yes I tried uninstalling all the versions I have, it didn't give me the error, but the python installation did the same on both installers.

Comment: @Hermione So now even after uninstalling VC++ 9, installing python gives the same error? Can you check your eventlog (eventvwr.msc) and let me know if there are any errors in it related to installation? (Note: Remember to re-install all the uninstalled versions of VC++ later. Else this will cause other applications on your machine to crash.)

Comment: @Hermione You had downloaded Python 2.7.3 MSI version right? The installer does not install VC++ 9 distibutable. Instead it directly tries to add the VC++ dlls to the WinSxS folder(C:\Windows\winsxs) (where VC++ dlls are installed). The event viewer should give more details on why the installation has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I remember getting the same error when I was trying to run a Python script on someone else's PC. Unfortunately I was in a hurry and did not have the time to look into it further, so on a hunch I just tried [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com) instead. It worked and I got the job done, so you you can try the same if at all you don't mind a portable installation.